# deployment strategies, PHP + SVN

Tags: php, svn, deployment, minify

i just wanna discuss our deployment strategy and find discrepancies in it. the process goes like this

-> Development finishes for a particular release

-> All developers commit their files to trunk

-> Compare database schemas using TOAD and migrate the changes

-> Create a new branch on SVN

-> Export using SVN (to remove .svn folder,etc)

-> minify the JS, CSS

-> upload to staging server

-> perform test cycle

-> fix bugs on the branch and verify them

-> re-minify the JS, CSS [if required]

-> upload to production server

-> when i say upload, it means uploading files through SSH to
   /var/www/html folder

-> first upload js, css, images

-> then upload php files

-> during upload exclude directories like user uploaded pictures, etc.

-> perform test cycle

-> fix bugs and upload again (may need re-minify - few files)

-> verify bugs

-> verification completes

-> commit branch to svn

-> merge changes back to the trunk

-> commit trunk [during this deployment cycle, no one commits any files to the trunk]

the process is really complicated and requires lots of attention.

any suggestions on how we can improve it?

Comment: Have the developers commit at least daily. Use a Schema Manager to automigrate the DB changes and version them in your VCS. Use a Continuous Integration server and a build tool like Phing. Have a look around SO. These topics have been discussed before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following deployment path.  It removes many of your needs to re-upload files to different directories.  After initial setup, the most complicated work you will have to do is "svn update" commands in each of your test locations.

This setup assumes you use config files for pointing to directories like assets, images, and css.

1. Init repository.  Always have a unique user for production and test checkouts.  This allows for unique commits from live server back to trunk in emergencies.
2. Devs develop and commit.  Builds are tagged with build number, as well as a tag for LIVE when they are supposed to be project ready.
3. Checkout is made on test server.  If everything goes swell. #dev.example.com/~test/project/
4. svn update to a test directory on production server.  #example.com/~test/project
5. svn update to your main project directory on production server to LIVE tag.  #example.com
6. If you have any exceptions in steps 3 through 5, return to step 2.

All projects have a config file, that allows one to set paths to development databases, shared images, etc.  config.dist.php works well as a naming schema.  Each checkout then copies config.dist.php to config.php. This allows for many configs without SVN collisions.

Each config file typically has some code such as

```
<?php
    #hopefully, your project can leave these first two constants set to '', because relative paths work for everything
         define('localPath', '/home/www/projectName');
         define('baseURL', 'http://example.com/~projectName');

    #if you want to write everything over a shared filesystem for instance, uploads.
         define('localAssetsDirectory', '/sharedFileSystem/localPath');

    #if you want to include a shared assets directory
         define('assetsURL', 'assets/images');

    #OR if you want to host assets in one location.
         define('assetsURL', 'http://assets.example.com/images/'    
 ?>
```

All test versions on production and dev server are only accessable by restricted ips, as well as put behind a .htaccess file.  Apache is configured to not serve .svn directories.

Comment: yeah.. i think this model makes sense and i was thinking on the same line..  we can have a svn server in our office .. and production server and staging server gets a svn update from the main repo.. also, we already have a configuration file like this .. thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: +1, exactly how you should do things! Also allows for replication when across load balanced servers by just doing svn update on each of the other servers

Answer (score 0):

if you're using unit testing (e.g. Selenium) you can use a build tool to script all of this

if not, i would just script the following steps:

- Export using SVN (to remove .svn folder,etc)
- minify the JS, CSS
- upload to staging server

and

- re-minify the JS, CSS [if required]
- upload to production server
- when i say upload, it means uploading files through SSH to /var/www/html folder
- first upload js, css, images
- then upload php files
- during upload exclude directories like user uploaded pictures, etc.

since you're already branching and merging, you should keep your trunk should always be a stable build with the latest features.
finally, TAG your releases

Comment: how can we achieve atomicity while uploading? coz there is every possibility of website breaking down during an upload.. should i upload to some other folder? then copy them on the server? the operation is little optimized but it may create its own problems like setting rights,etc.

Comment: trunk should only be merged with 100% working branches. you can export the changed files between the trunk and the current branch to create a set of files to upload